# command for opening android studio

Tags: execute-command

I recently installed easystroke on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system. I want to add a shortcut stroke for the same. Can you guys tell me what command to use?
location of android studio is

```
/home/antony/Documents/Android Studio Installation Files/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

for other apps like firefox i use

```
 wmctrl -a Firefox || firefox
```

but this does not work for android studio

also

```
xdg-open of /home/....
```

opens the bash file in text editor instead of terminal..

Pls help me out guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this command:

```
wmctrl -a "Android Studio" || "/home/antony/Documents/Android Studio Installation Files/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"
```

Use the full path with double quotes.

---

from `man wmctrl`

```
   -a <WIN>
          Switch to the desktop containing the window <WIN>, raise the window, and  give  it
          focus.


   <WIN>  This argument specifies a window that is the target of an action. By  default  the
          argument  is  treated  as  if were a string, and windows are examined until one is
          found with a title the contains the specified string as a substring. The substring
          matching  is done in a case insensitive manner. The -F option may be used to force
          exact, case sensitive title matching. The option -i may be used to  interpret  the
          window target as a numeric window identity instead of a string.
```

Comment: for some weird reason it didn work at first . now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xdotool type "sh '/home/antony/Documents/Android Studio Installation Files/android-studio/bin/studio.sh'" ; xdotool key KP_Enter
```

if not work try this then:

```
wmctrl -a "Android Studio" || "/home/antony/Documents/Android Studio Installation Files/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"
```

Comment: sorry bt that didnt work  :(

Comment: @ChrisAbyAntony check my edit

Comment: Had we really the same idea at the same time? =)

Comment: @A.B. It's really not my idea , I just use this http://www.timelessguru.com/easystroke :)

Comment: yeah this works perfect but seems that A.B. posted it first

Comment: @ChrisAbyAntony Good don't matter